# Margin property not being passed as props

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a styled component that will recieve a prop so it tells it if it should give it a margin-left or right.

I think I am having a syntax problem

I will paste some code:

```
const FormDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  ${({ left }) =>
    css`
     *** margin${'-'}${left ? 'right' : 'left'}: 30vw; ***
    `};

  @media ${device.mobileS} {
    height: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  @media ${device.tablet} {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
  }
`;

export default FormDiv;
```

When I try to pass left or right inside the component it doesnt take any sort of margin. What can be done to fix the syntax of the bold sentence

Answer (score 1):

From https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#can-i-nest-rules

```js
const FormDiv = styled.div`
  ...

  ${props => props.left ? "margin-right" : "margin-left"}: 30vw;

  ...
`
```

or

```js
  ${props => props.left 
      ? 'margin-right: 30vw;'
      : 'margin-left: 30vw;'}
```

or

```js
  ${props => props.left 
      ? css`margin-right: 30vw;`
      : css`margin-left: 30vw;`}
```

or

```js
  margin-right: 30vw;

  ${props => props.left && css`
       margin-right: unset;
       margin-left: 30vw;`}
```